# Why can't I deploy a tutorial-netword in Playground Composer?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Ubuntu 16.04, just installed the Hyperledger composer and all its prereqs.  I created a PeerAdmin card, I started the Composer Playground locally.

Trying to follow this basic tutorial:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/playground-tutorial.html

Step2:  Creating new business network
I entered the name (tutorial-network), optional description, selected 'empty-business-network'.   This is all the tutorial says that is required to Deploy this network, but my browser has the "Deploy" button grayed out.... not allowing me to deploy. I also tried entering Admin in the Network Admin Card Name.  That didn't help. I couldn't figure out any other options below that would make the Deploy button clickable.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

Within Hyperledger Composer Playground there are 2 types of connections (e.g., hlfv1 and Web Browser).  Each of those has "Deploy a new business network."  Deploying a new business network from the hlfv1 connection section does not provide an enabled "Deploy" button.  If you deploy a new business network from the Web Browser connection, the button is enabled.

Comment: You can switch the connection on the initial playground page.

Answer (score 2):

Is your Fabric running?  If is is not running, you will see the greyed out button.

You can run the command `docker ps` to see if your Development Fabric is running, and there should be 4 containers.

If you have restarted your machine it is likely the Fabric is not running.  If you previously had no data on the Fabric, then you can just issue the `startFabric.sh` script frpom the fabricTools folder.

Comment: In addition, you also need to run `createPeerAdminCard.sh` if the default card is not created beforehand.